# Cursorloader sort order alphabetical then numeric

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

Is it possible to sort the results alphabetically and then numerically when pulling data from the Contacts table?

Code snippet:

```
    cursorLoader.setSortOrder(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC, " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " ASC, " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC, " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
```

This results in numerical values appearing before alphabetical values

Comment: Please include an example of the sorted data indicating what data is for what column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the display name can contain numbers and names and you want the numbers to appear last e.g.

[image]

And you want Fred to appear before 01 23456 7890 but say for Alan to appear before Fred then one way would be to introduce a means of detecting whether or not the value is a number. This can be accomplished by trying to convert the value to a number (integer in this example) using a CAST.

So instead of :-

```
SELECT * FROM phonedata ORDER BY display_name ASC, contact_id ASC, is_super_primary DESC, is_primary DESC
```

which results in :-

[image]

You could use something along the lines of :-

```
SELECT 
    CAST(replace(display_name,' ','') AS INTEGER) AS converted,
    * 
FROM phonedata 
ORDER BY CAST(replace(display_name,' ','') AS INTEGER) ASC,  
    display_name ASC, 
    contact_id ASC, 
    is_super_primary DESC, 
    is_primary DESC
```

This would produce :-

[image]

#### Notes

- The converted column has been included for illustration.

  - That is it shows how an alphabetic value will result in 0 from the CAST, thus making it top order for the sort, whilst a numeric value (except 0)
- You may need to tailor the above but basically the principle applies

Comment: Trying it out. Seems promising